# Issue Merging two lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am attempting to merge two lists with data that exists and data that does not exist and return both.

Basically, when passed a startDate and endDate I need to extract the months between and create a list and then make a call to the database and retrieve the data and merge it into the first list.  I've done this successfully.  However, I need to return the entire list instead of just the Months with data.

```
startDate is 5-1-2016
endate is 7-14-2016
```

Code:

```
 //Create the empty list
        if (dateRange == "m")
        {

            List<DataObject> MonthList = new List<DataObject>();

            for (DateTime dt = startDate; dt <= endDate; dt = dt.AddMonths(1))
            {
                var insertDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
                MonthList.Add(new DataObject
                {
                    data_date = insertDate,
                    dataParam1 = 0,
                    dataParam2 = 0,
                    dataParam3 = 0,
                    dataParam4 = 0,
                    dataParam5 = 0
                });
           }

 //Get the Data

          List<DataObject> value =
                  dctx.QueryStoredProcedure<DataObject>("sproc",
                       parameters).ToList();
```

//Merge the Lists

```
  var result = value.Join(MonthList, arg => arg.data_date, arg => arg.data_date,
              (x, y) =>
                  new DataObject
                  {
                      data_date = y.data_date,
                      dataParam1 = x.Calories,
                      dataParam2 = x.ActiveMinutes,
                      dataParam3 = x.Duration,
                      dataParam4 = x.Distance,
                      dataParam5 = x.Steps
                  }).ToList();
```

Expected results :

```
"data_date": "2016-05-01T00:00:00",
"dataParam1": 195007,
"dataParam2": 163069,
"dataParam3": 0,
"dataParam4": 0,
"dataParam5": 951087

"data_date": "2016-06-01T00:00:00",
"dataParam1": 416647,
"dataParam2": 265536,
"dataParam3": 0,
"dataParam4": 0,
"dataParam5": 1650185

"data_date": "2016-07-01T00:00:00",
"dataParam1": 0,
"dataParam2": 0,
"dataParam3": 0,
"dataParam4": 0,
"dataParam5": 0
```

Actual Results : (07-01-2016 is missing)

```
"data_date": "2016-05-01T00:00:00",
"dataParam1": 195007,
"dataParam2": 163069,
"dataParam3": 0,
"dataParam4": 0,
"dataParam5": 951087

"data_date": "2016-06-01T00:00:00",
"dataParam1": 416647,
"dataParam2": 265536,
"dataParam3": 0,
"dataParam4": 0,
"dataParam5": 1650185
```

I am sure it is in the merge, but I have attempted also trying to do a GroupJoin but I was unable to get the y values to populate with the object properties. I am clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question? Please accept if it did, or let me know what else I can help with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an outer join, which will return all results from first set, and match where possible, giving nulls in the second set where no match is found.

```
var result = (from month in MonthList
    join v in value on month.data_date equals v.data_date into vg
    join v in vg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DataObject
              {
                  data_date = month.data_date,
                  dataParam1 = v?.Calories ?? 0,
                  dataParam2 = v?.ActiveMinutes ?? 0,
                  dataParam3 = v?.Duration ?? 0,
                  dataParam4 = v?.Distance ?? 0,
                  dataParam5 = v?.Steps ?? 0
              }).ToList();
```

That said, this seems like a really strange way to do things. You should rather be handling missing months in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intersection, not a join

```
list.Intersect(otherList);
```